# java subclasses and constructor error

Tags: java, subclass

I have 3 classes in following order for checkers game

`Position` - contain methods and variables about position of a Piece (element in the game).

`Piece` - abstract class which contain general methods that are common to checker and king pieces.

`King` - contain methods relevant to king piece

In the `King` class, I have following constructor on which i got error

```
public class King extends Piece
{   
    public King(Piece checker)
    {
        super(checker.getColor(),checker.getPosition());
    }
}
```

In `Piece` class I have following:

```
public abstract class Piece {

    private Position newPiecePosition;
    private CheckersColor pieceColor;


    /**
     * Create new piece (checker / king)
     * @param color - color of the new piece
     * @param position - position of the new piece
     */
    public Piece(CheckersColor color, Position position)
    {
        pieceColor = color;
        newPiecePosition = new Position(position);
    }


    private Position getPosition()
    {
        Position position = new Position(newPiecePosition.getColumn(), newPiecePosition.getRow());

        return position;
    }

}
```

Where I'm wrong and how to solve it?

Comment: Why wouldn't you specify the error?

Comment: Setters and getters should be public, that's the point.

Comment: you are right. get color should be there, but i don't' have any problem with it. the problem is with checker.getPosition()

Comment: `King` is a `Piece`. Why does it need to take a `Piece` argument?

Comment: in chackers once some piece is reaching last line, it is switches to a king. the piece is old checker

Answer (score 2):

Well, one problem :

`private Position getPosition()`

You can't access a private method from the sub-class's constructor :

```
public King(Piece checker)
{
    super(checker.getColor(),checker.getPosition()); // you are getting a 
                                                     // compilation error here
}
```

Getters are usually public.

Comment: this is the limitation of the exercise,
any additional methods beyond those described, should be private

Comment: Teacher demands private methods? Troll him with reflection :3 But seriously, if your teacher teaches you to write private getters, I feel sorry for you (wo)man.

Comment: I wrote it. there is getter in the Position class.
How can I access to it?